# Using Websocket and http server together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am using websocket and http server together, assigning each of them a different port, when a post request hits it sends a message to client using websocket and response of http request is send when client responds to the message.

My problem is I want to create multiple websockets but a single https server, I have tried some things but unable to do it.

Current code for creating websocket and httpserver is

```
const app = require('express')()
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const net = require('net');
var client;
var res1,currentReq;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests listener
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.listen(8001, () => console.log('Http server listening on port 8001'));

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// http requests handling
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.post('/getUser', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
res1 = res;
currentReq='getUser';
    client.write('{"route":"/","data":{"username":"' + req.body.username +'"}, "res": "' + res + '"}');
//res.end('{"Extension":"' +' data '+ '"}');

console.log("/getUser finished");
   // res.end('{"Extension":"' +' data '+ '"}');

  });

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Establishing tcp connection for incoming requests
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
   console.log ('client has connected successfully!');
   client = connection;
   client.on('data',function(data){
   switch(currentReq) 
   {
       case 'getUser' :
                    console.log('send get user response');
                    res1.end(data);
                    break;

   }

    console.log(data.toString());
            //res1.end(data);

  });

   connection.pipe(connection);
});


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// listener for tcp connections
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

server.listen(8000, function() {
   console.log('server for localhost is listening on port 8000');
   console.log('server bound address is: ' + server.address ());
});
```

Comment: Uh, a webSocket client MUST connect to a webSocket server, not a plain TCP server.  A webSocket has a whole connection scheme (that starts with an http request and then upgrades to the webSocket protocol), encryption security scheme and data frame format.  You have to use all of those.  So, your `net.createServer()` will not work for a webSocket.

Comment: You can use ONE http server for both regular http requests and incoming webSocket connections.  webSocket server code can listen to the incoming http requests and pick off just the ones that are actually webSocket connection requests. 
 There is no need to have multiple separate servers on separate ports.

Comment: Also, `connection.pipe(connection);` makes no sense.  It's unclear what you think that does or what you're trying to do.  You don't pipe to yourself.

Comment: i am writing websocket code for first time, thanks for pointing it out i will study what it does

Comment: also i want to use multiple ports as i cannot change the port with which http client connects but want to have multiple websocket clients.

Comment: There's typically no reason to use a separate port for a webSocket connection.  It can happily share the same port/server as the http server.  And, I've never seen a good reason for putting multiple websocket servers on the same host either as you can just the same webSocket connection for lots of different things, just like you use the same http server for lots of different types of requests.  It seems to me like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: thanks, i think i was trying a use case that was not possible